# How to raise an error with PostgreSQL select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a data patching script and I'd like to rollback the transaction when some condition occurs.

I could do something like this in the end of the script:

```
select t.id / 0
from some_table t
where t.state = 'undersirable state'
```

but I'd rather have a more appropriate error message than "division by zero".

Is there a generic function for generating errors in PostgreSQL? I'd like to do it without PL/SQL, if possible.

Comment: *"Is there a generic function for generating errors in PostgreSQL? I'd like to do it without PL/SQL, if possible."* No there isn't anny for plain queries like these..

Comment: "I'd like to do it without PL/SQL" - How come? If you just want to avoid creating a function, you can run it from a [`DO` block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

Comment: @NickBarnes within a script, like the OP here was writing, yeah, that's a valid approach. I've still sometimes specifically wanted an *expression* that throws an error, though, for use as e.g. the default value of a `CASE` expression used within a `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 6):

Write a little function that raises the error for you and use that in your `SELECT` statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION raise_error() RETURNS integer
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   RAISE EXCEPTION /* whatever you want */;
   RETURN 42;
END;$$;
```

Comment: That is brilliant!
It is so obvious solution, yet I did not find it from any other place.

Comment: function [raise_exception()](https://github.com/rin-nas/postgresql-patterns-library/blob/master/functions/raise_exception.sql)